# default constructor for a class which contains character pointer and a character array

Tags: c++

I have designed the class as below

But i am getting runtime error while executing it.

Please let me know the solutions for the below

1. Why does Line3 in main gives compilation errors (what do i need to do if i want to initialize only one member of the class)
2. Why do i get run time error for Line 4.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class A{

    int age;
    char *name;
    char info[50];

    public:
    A(int p_age=0,char *p_name=NULL,char p_info[]=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Constructor called"<<endl;
        age=p_age;
        int length1=strlen(p_name)+1;
        int length2=strlen(p_info)+1;
        strncpy(name,p_name,length1);
        name[length1-1]='\0';
        strncpy(info,p_info,length2);
        info[length2-1]='\0';
    }

    void get()
    {
        cout<<"Enter the age";
        cin>>age;
        cout<<"Enter name & info";
        gets(name);
        gets(info);
    }

    void display()
    {
        cout<<age<<name<<info;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A obj(20,"Ename","Stud");
    obj.display();
    // A obj1("EEEE");//Line3
    A obj2;    //Line 4
    obj2.get();
    obj2.display();
}
```

Comment: why not using std::string and thus save yourself errors ?

Answer (score 1):

`A obj1("EEEE")` is an error because the first parameter to your constructor is declared as an `int p_age` and the compiler cannot automatically cast `"EEEE"` into an `int`. Trying to initialize `obj2` causes an error because you have provided no parameter in the call, so the default values are used, and when the line `int length1=strlen(p_name)+1;` is executed, `strlen()` crashes from accessing memory from `p_name`, which is NULL.

Comment: so how do we correct this ?Wat should be the proper constructor body

Comment: @user3492389 Several things are needed. I would suggest having multiple constructors; at least the one you have and also `A(char *p_name==NULL, p_info[]=NULL)` That way you can skip the first parameter if you wish when declaring an object. Then for your pointers, if they are null, do not copy them ut instead indicate NULL values for your member variables. You also have not allocated any memory for `name` in case it is not null. All of these things should be done.

Comment: OK i got it Thanks.. Lets say i have allocated for name as name = new char[length1]  . Now how would i have the destructor for this class shall i call delete for name inside it?

Comment: @user3492389 Yes you could simply have `delete name;`

Answer (score 0):

name is not allocated.

```
...
int length1=strlen(p_name)+1;
int length2=strlen(p_info)+1;
name = new char[length1]; // add this line
strncpy(name,p_name,length1);
    name[length1-1]='\0';
strncpy(info,p_info,length2);
    info[length2-1]='\0';
...
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first argument in constructor is `int` and you are trying to pass `const char*`.
2. The default initialization for your `p_name` is NULL and `strlen` of null gives segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

In the declaration

```
A obj2
```

you do not provide the `p_name` and `p_info` arguments, so they are defaulted to NULL. Then in the constructor you call

```
strlen(p_name)
```

on `p_name` which is NULL. This is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Let C++ help you.

```
class A{

    int age;
    std::string name;
    std::string info;

public:
    explicit A(int p_age = 0, const std::string& p_name = "", const std::string& p_info = "")
        : age(p_age)
        , name(p_name)
        , info(p_info)
    {
    }
};
```